# How can I find a string inside a bs4.ResultSet (list) using Python?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to automate searching for ads in Facebook Ads Library. For that, I've used Selenium and BeautifulSoup to get the page's code.

The BeautifulSoup function returns a ***bs4.ResultSet*** with the page's HTML, which as I understand is a list.

I'm trying to loop through that list with ***soup.find_all***, and for each element that is found, I want to test and see if there's a specific string in that.

But actually, my code isn't working as expected. The *if* statement inside the *for loop* always returns False.

```
# Using chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

# Web page url request
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/?active_status=all&ad_type=all&country=BR&q=frete%20gr%C3%A1tis%20aproveite&sort_data[direction]=desc&sort_data[mode]=relevancy_monthly_grouped&search_type=keyword_unordered&media_type=all')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(10)

# Webscraping with BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser') 

ads_list = []
for tag in soup.find_all('div', class_='_99s5'):
    if 'qku1pbnj j8otv06s r05nras9 a1itoznt te7ihjl9 svz86pwt a53abz89' in str(tag):
        ads_list.append(tag)
    else:
        None
```

Comment: Cause class names are dynamic, are you sure one of these is in your `soup`? Would be easier if you could point out the element your expecting to find. Maybe it could be located with another strategy.

Comment: First, I'm using *soup.find_all* to find all divs with class '_99s5'. Then, I'm checking each found div to see if there's a span with the class 'qku1pbnj j8otv06s r05nras9 a1itoznt te7ihjl9 svz86pwt a53abz89' inside the first div ('_99s5'). If the span exists, I'll use the div, if not, I'll ignore it.

Comment: Still understood that part also from your question. But these classes do not exist for some reasons, so could you provide anything (tag, id, text) what is in this `span` or around it that enables us to identify it. Would be great.

Comment: The `span` that I'm looking for always has the text `n ads use this creative and text`, beeing `n` a variable number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned before, the strategy of using classes is not the best, as they can be very dynamic, so it would be better to stick to id, tag or perhaps text - but sometimes there may be no alternatives.

To select only the cards with a `<span>` containing the information that it has been used in ads, you can work with `css selectors`.

Following line will search for your outer `<div>` with class `_99s5`, that has a `<span>` containing your text and creates a `ResultSet` with these outer `<div>`:

```
ads_list = soup.select('div._99s5:has(:-soup-contains("ads use this creative and text"))')
```

#### Example

**Note:** *Language of your browser/driver should be englisch, else you have to change the text you expect to find.*

```
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/?active_status=all&ad_type=all&country=BR&q=frete%20gr%C3%A1tis%20aproveite&sort_data[direction]=desc&sort_data[mode]=relevancy_monthly_grouped&search_type=keyword_unordered&media_type=all')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(10)

# Webscraping with BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser') 

ads_list = soup.select('div._99s5:has(:-soup-contains("ads use this creative and text"))')
```

---

Alternativ, not that happy about, but to give you an orientation would be to select the `<div>` with a direct child `<span>` containing your text and move up the structure with `.parent`:

```
ads_list = []

for tag in soup.select('div > span:-soup-contains("ads use this creative and text")'):
    ads_list.append(tag.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent)
```

Comment: That is what I needed. Can you take a look at this other question I've asked?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71429213/delete-dynamic-element-with-selenium-python-and-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 1):

The following statement:

```
if 'qku1pbnj j8otv06s r05nras9 a1itoznt te7ihjl9 svz86pwt a53abz89' in str(tag)
```

will return `True` if and only if `'qku1pbnj j8otv06s r05nras9 a1itoznt te7ihjl9 svz86pwt a53abz89'` is a substring of `str(tag)`. I assume that you rather want to check whether `str(tag)` contains any of strings `'qku1pbnj j8otv06s r05nras9 a1itoznt te7ihjl9 svz86pwt a53abz89'`. So it will be:

```
if any(e in str(tag) for e in 'qku1pbnj j8otv06s r05nras9 a1itoznt te7ihjl9 svz86pwt a53abz89'.split()):
```

Comment: That line is always returning True, even though it should return False in some cases. The string 'qku1pbnj j8otv06s r05nras9 a1itoznt te7ihjl9 svz86pwt' doesn't always exist.

Comment: @AirãCarvalhodaSilva, no it does not: `any(e in str('') for e in 'qku1pbnj j8otv06s r05nras9 a1itoznt te7ihjl9 svz86pwt a53abz89'.split())` returns `False`. How is the `tag` constructed? Can you display it?

Comment: `for tag in soup.find_all('div', class_='_99s5'):

    if any(e in str(tag) for e in 'qku1pbnj j8otv06s r05nras9 a1itoznt te7ihjl9 svz86pwt a53abz89'.split()):
        print('OK')
    else:
        print ('Not OK')`

Comment: Sorry, pressed Enter and sent the code with no further clarification. I'm constructing the tag from elements that come from a *soup.find_all*. The soup.find_all is exactly the bs4.ResultSet or list that I'm checking if the string exists.

Comment: @AirãCarvalhodaSilva I would start with checking what is returned by `str(tag)`. I suppose you're misusing it.